# 2010 camaro v6 camshaft position sensor

Tags: chevrolet, camaro, camshaft-position-sensor

Can anybody tell me the location of the the sensor for my Camaro? I would like to replace it and I can't seem to find anything online.

Car: 2010 Camaro LT v6 3.6L

Error Code: P0017 Crankshaft Position - Camshaft position correlation - bank 1 sensor B

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

P0017 code is not for the camshaft position sensor, but telling you the bank 1 exhaust camshaft is out of time with the rest of the engine. This can be caused from several different reasons, none of them being the sensor itself (for either camshaft or crankshaft position sensors). The following are [reasons for the code](https://www.autoblog.com/2016/03/28/p0017-obd-ii-trouble-code-crankshaft-position-camshaft-positi/):

- The valve timing is out of position from a timing chain jumped out of position.
- There are oil flow problems to the phaser from incorrect oil viscosity or partly clogged passages.
- The oil control valve (OCV) has a restriction in the OCV filter.
- There is an exhaust timing gear problem with phaser causing camshaft misalignment.

The most probable culprit being not using the correct oil for your engine. Second to that being the cam phaser on the bank 1 (that's the exhaust cam on the right side of the engine) isn't working correctly. Thirdly, it could be if the chain is worn out, the cam gear has actually slipped a tooth.

One of the diagnostic checks is to ensure the wiring to both the cam and crank sensors are still good and connected correctly. To that end, you'll find the sensors at in the following image at position 4 for camshaft position sensor and 11 for crankshaft position sensor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and diagram. I'll try to debug the issue as best as I can with your advice.